# Trying to send an email while using Xammp

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am trying to send an email using Xammp. It's returning the success message but the mail is not sent.

I've tried using the code below but its not sending the mail despite returning the success message.

This is the code;

```
<?php
include ('config.php'); 

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$first_name  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['first_name']);
$last_name   = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['last_name']);
$email    = $_POST['email'];
$phone   = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['comments']);
$DateCreated = date('Y-m-d');


$address = "abc@gmail.com";

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $first_name . '.';

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $first_name.". PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $first_name via email, dce@gmail.com or via phone $phone";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: xxx@gmail.com" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: xxx@gmail.com" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h1>Email Sent Successfully.</h1>";
    echo "<p>Thank you <strong>$first_name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";
} else {
    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

Comment: Do you have an SMTP Server installed? You can only send an E-Mail when you have a mail server to send it. You can use PHP to connect to your mail server but you can never send one without.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this issue is not a coding issue but a missing SMTP-Server (Mail-Server).

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`!